# PostGIS trigger : table and materialized view

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, function, trigger

I have a PostGIS polygons table for my "cities".
I have a point table for my "boreholl".

I created a "mv" materialized view defined by a spatial join as follows:

```
SELECT boreholl.*,
       cities.gid,
       cities.insee_id,
       cities.name
FROM   boreholl, cities
WHERE  st_intersects(boreholl.geom, cities.geom);
```

Now I want as soon as an updating takes place for the "cities_name" column of my "cities" polygon table,
this change also occurs in the "name" column of my materialized view.

As far I understood,the trigger must be defined on the "cities" table as follows :

```
CREATE TRIGGER cities_trigger
after  update
on cities
FOR EACH STATEMENT. 
execute procedure trigger_function
```

Now I need to define the function. It is for this step that I need you.
Below, a proposed structure. But a lot is missing :

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION  trigger_function
returns trigger
langage sql
AS $$
BEGIN
 if    then
update
end if ;
return new
refresh materialized view
END;
$$
```

Comment: Trigger functions are supposed to be very quick events, since they're inside a commit. Trying to propagate a materialized view inside a trigger has got to be worst practice (if it's even possible).

Comment: Have you considered a view, rather than a marterialised view?

Comment: I considered the matérialised view rather than view because I read that the writing on a MV was faster. But considering your messages, as far as understood, the best way would be to store the join into a view. Then to set a trigger?

Comment: no need for a trigger if you use a view - just make sure there is a suitable index

Answer (score 2):

Creating a *materialised view* executes a query and writes the result to disk. It will only update the result set when told to do so (`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW {view table}`).

A *view* will only execute the query when the view itself is queried (i.e. `SELECT * FROM {view table}` is essentially a proxy to the query defined by the `CREATE VIEW` command). A view is therefore not physically *materialised* (hence the name distinction).

So querying a non-materialised view will retrieve the latest information, **there is no need for an insert trigger**. Whether this is a better option for you than a materialised view depends on how long the query takes, and how often updates occur. I tend to use views a lot more frequently than materialised views, which I usually reserve for cases of heavy spatial operators.

If you still want to use a materialised view (there are good reasons this may be so), and you want the latest updates in your result set, then you must use `REFRESH MATERIALISED VIEW` before querying your view. Using an insert trigger is still an option, I think, but it probably isn't a good idea since triggers are meant to be quick record-level updates — I tend to use them for things like deriving geometries, e.g. so I can have a polygon and its centroid pre-calculated and available in the same table.